# Measure formuation of a conservation law

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, geometric-measure-theory

Let $u$ be a $BV$ entropy-solution of the scalar conservation law
$$u_t(x,t) + f(u(x,t))_x = 0$$
It is claimed that then (since the derivatives of a $BV$ function are measures) it holds in the sense of measures that

$$D_tu + \lambda D_xu = 0$$

where
$$\lambda(t,x) = \begin{cases}
f^{\prime}(u(t,x)) & if \quad (t,x)\quad  \text{is continuity point of $u$} \\
\frac{f(u^+)-f(u^-)}{u^+-u^-}& if \quad (t,x) \quad \text{is a point of jump for $u$}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, i tried to prove this using the structure theorem for the derivatives of $BV$ functions, but I can't manage to recover the above formula. Does someone know how to do that? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't swapped the conditions on $u$ in definition of $\lambda$?

Comment: oh yes, thanks very much for pointing that out, now i have edited it